# Core Data 2 different relationship from one entity to another

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I want to have this model :

```
Feature -> Image (relationship name: image inverse: feature)
Feature -> Image (relationship name: thumb inverse: feature)

Image -> Feature (relationship name: feature inverse: ????)
```

I can setup only one inverse. But it looks that i need both: `image` and `thumb`

**UPDATE**

One of the way is to create this model:

Picture has all that we need from Image
Image inherit picture
Thumb inherit picture

they share NSManagedObject Class.

Is this correct?

**UPDATE 2**

After @StuDev help my model looks like.

[image: Model version 2.0]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting up a model that looks something like this:

[image: Multiple entity sample core data model]

So using your notation:

```
Feature -> Image (destination: Image, inverse: feature)
Feature -> Thumb (destination: Thumb, inverse: feature)
```

Or, the other way around (the same thing really):

```
Image -> Feature (destination: Feature, inverse: image)
Thumb -> Feature (destination: Feature, inverse: thumb)
```

This way you keep access to your thumb and image separate, so you only need to load the one you need at that time. You shouldn't have a *need* to store the image and thumb within the same entity (correct me if I'm wrong...), so this setup keeps things nice and clear.


**EDIT**

Alternatively, if you would like to keep the image and thumb within the same `NSManagedObject` subclass (as you suggest in your update), then combine these as attributes within an entity "Picture" (or whatever you want to call it):

[image: Single entity sample core data model]

Using this approach, when you want to access either the image or thumbnail of a given feature, simply fault to the feature's picture, and then access the image or thumb:

```
UIImage *theThumbnail = [feature.picture thumb];  // Assuming you are storing the image & thumb as a transformable (UIImage) type
```

Comment: Can (or need) i create general parent for (`Image` and `Thumb`)?

Comment: @DAloG: You don't need to create any other kind of parent for the `Image` and `Thumb` entities. Any entity can be accessed in the data model, regardless of whether it is connected to another entity. The relationship between the 'Image' and 'Feature', or 'Thumb' and 'Feature' makes your data model easier to manage, by allowing you to fault the required data if you already have already fetched the feature, rather than manually fetching it. Technically, you could still access a given feature's image if there were no relationship between the two, but this would be unnecessarily long-winded!